# Selenium Unable to select a date from date picker

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

unable to select a date from date picker

this is the website working on https://www.phptravels.net/

when i used developer options and Ctrl + F on firebug
//div[@style='display: block; top: 390px; left: 680px;']//text()[contains(.,'15')]

i am able to find the date on the page

but when i am trying from the code i am unable to select the element

This is my code

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@style='display: block; top: 390px; left: 680px;']//text()[contains(.,'"+start_date+"')]").click()


test_Flight.py:37: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\pages\search_flights_form.py:68: in set_start_date_pick
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@style='display: block; top: 390px; left: 680px;']//text()[contains(.,'15')]").click()
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:976: in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x052D6D18>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: //div[@style=\'disp...ntent/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5\\nelement.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16\\n"}}'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below and confirm.

```
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

checkin = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"checkin")))
checkin.click()

date = 15
select_date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f"//div[@class='datepicker-days']//td[text()='{date}']")))
select_date.click()
```

Update: As per comments to select date from Flights section.

```
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

flights = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-controls='flights']")))
flights.click()

departure_date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@class,'depart')]")))
departure_date.click()

date = 15
select_date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f"(//div[@class='datepicker-days'])[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[text()='{date}']")))
select_date.click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, It did not work, and it is not unique, actually with this xpath locator //div[@class='datepicker-days']//td[text()='{date}'] there are '7' matching elements on the webpage,

Comment: @Learner - Yes, there were 7 matches. But by default it will select the 1st element. And it worked fine for me. It did select 15 for Check in.

Comment: ok, but when i was verifying using the Ctrl +F , for me it was 3rd time search was successful, for your code i got time out exception error ( iam selecting Round trip / filling From and to ) then selecting the date

Comment: See update. And share the exact path. I am in Hotels->Check in. Are you taking about Flights->Departure Date?

Comment: ( sorry for confusion ) Yes, i am talking about Flights -> Departure date

Comment: See update now.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks one question why my selector was not working my XPath was unique on the page?

Comment: @Learner - Actually that Xpath did not highlight the element in the DOM. So created one. Try to go for attributes like `ID`, `NAME`, `CLASS`. My opinion - `STYLE` should be last option. And `//text()` was throwing error. Once Refer this - https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/