# Selenium Select the exact date from Datepciker

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is continuation of this question asked earlier [Earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71346348/selenium-unable-to-select-a-date-from-date-picker)

I am able to select the date but the problem arises in below scenarios when there is some dates like

```
<td class="day disabled old">28</td>
<td class="day  active">15</td>
<td class="day  new">19</td>
<td class="day ">28</td>
```

I tried using XPath not contains but I am getting more than 1 element identified.

below is my code

```
(//div[@class='datepicker-days'])[3]/table/tbody//td[not(contains(class,'disabled'))][text()='28']

<td class="day disabled ">28</td>
<td class="day ">28</td>
```

I want to select only the dates which are below

```
<td class="day  active">15</td>
<td class="day ">16</td>
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicate `[not(contains(class,'disabled'))]` is not working as you should use `@class` not `class`:

```
[not(contains(@class,'disabled'))]
```